# Is this possible for a Windows based machine to send and receive data to tailor made app on the iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, windows, excel

I am making an app for the iPhone in Xcode which needs to be able to send and receive excel data from a windows based machine.  Making the app is no trouble but what would I need from a PC to access the app data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. If I did understand, then what you need is a server your app can connect to (and your PC, if it's not going to be the server itself).

Comment: More information is needed as to how you expect to access the data from the PC - as to whether that's the server for the app to put data on, or if the PC is a different machine all together.  Are you trying to write an app that runs on the PC to access the same file?

Comment: XCode has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @sosborn - I wondering if there was anything I could do in XCode to aid with the data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I wouldn't be using Excel as a data storage program.  What you really should be using is a database hosted on a web server with a PHP interface etc.  If you choose to go the database route, then you can easily use a Windows machine.

Though if you choose to stick with Excel, it would be theoretically be possible given that people have made apps to have full control of a computer remotely via an app.  I just think that this approach is going to be very hard to set up, and will be a lot more clunky than any sort of web server set up.  Don't forget that you can get free web server services if the data level is low.

As you mentioned, this PC won't have access to the internet.  Assuming you aren't willing to fix that, I guess you'd be left with a Bluetooth or local wifi option.  Having to plug it in would really defeat the purpose of an app, and I don't think that iPhones can even do that without mad hacks.

An alternative idea is to build an app that links in with some free web server service, then build VBA code to download it to your Excel sheet.  When you plug your iPhone into your PC, use the hotspot to get internet access.

Comment: Basically my main issue is trying to figure out a way for an app to send/receive data to a windows machine which does not has access to the internet.

Comment: So what's the basic idea?  So you can sit at your couch and work on your excel sheet instead of at your computer?  Without your PC having access to the internet, it sounds really not useful.. .  Though I

Comment: Wow... so what's the purpose?  To be able to sit at your couch with your iPhone and work on the spreadsheet instead of being at your PC?  If you explain more, perhaps we can come up with a better solution for you.

Comment: You could 1) create an ad-hoc network between the PC and the iphone. This would allow you to use the internet protocol without accessing the internet, or 2) sync documents over usb with itunes. I am not sure how to do 2) and 1) would be more confortable to use anyway (wireless).

Comment: @andrewb - the purpose doesn't really matter. He simply wants to share data between a local PC and his iPhone app, which is definitely possible assuming the PC has the right interfaces (WiFi).

Comment: @sosborn The purpose does matter, because he could be trying to solve a problem with an inferior solution.  E.g. perhaps the problem is easily and more effectively solved with a web hosted database, so that he could carry on work not just when he's near his PC.  Building iPhone integration with Excel can't be that great.  I suppose we could just ignore his purpose and just answer his explicit question, but I tend to prefer finding the best solution to problems.

Comment: @andrewb I totally agree that this project is not something I would ever want to do, but it seems pretty clear the intent is share with the local PC, which is a legitimate requirement for many cases.Not everyone has the resources to do a web hosted solution, and not every user wants to bother with a web hosted solution. As a good example, look at how Coda on the Mac interfaces with iOS.

Comment: Basically it is an app that I would use to store data when I’m out and about (not near a computer). Then when I’m near a windows computer, I can easily transfer my data from the iphone using a lead - which would open into an excel spread sheet on the computer  Sorry if it sounds like a complicated/confusing question but it is a complicated/confusing problem.

Comment: Ok I've amended my answer.  Basically I don't think you can do it via a lead without any wifi network action.  Though I'm thinking that this is all going to be a very hard task, a lot harder than say setting up even a local web server (or getting a free online service) to store the data, then build some VBA stuff for your excel sheet to download the data.